# 2 different `Content-Encoding` on 2 different aspnet core webapi `Actions`

Tags: asp.net-web-api, gzip, content-encoding

I have `Controller1/Action1`, which currently don't care about `Accept-Encoding` in request and return `application/json` response always.

Now in same application, we are adding `Controller2/Action2`, which will return huge json (~5mb) and want to use compression and decided to go with `gzip`. Our `new client_2` of `Controller2/Action2` are ready to consume it as `gzip`.

Though `Controller1/Action1` still has to return `Content-Encoding` as `application/json` and NOT `gzip`, as I don't think all `client_1s` of `Controller1/Action1` passes `Accept-Encoding` header.

So how can I achieve 2 different `Content-Encoding` on 2 different `Actions`.

Adding below compression in aspnet pipeline results gzip for all Actions and will not return `JSON` for `Controller1/Action1` which I want always, as I don't think all `client_1s` has capability to consume `gzip`

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddResponseCompression(options => { options.EnableForHttps = true; });
            services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
            });
        }
```

Adding only below attribute on Action seems not having any effect either, I am not getting back any response

```
[Produces("application/gzip")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you compress using GZip, the Action Controller2/Action2 always return data in binary format. So you have to change the "Content-Encoding" in the response Header to binary.
For Example, In the response header, try giving the following

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept Encoding
```

In the request header, give the following,

```
Accept-Encoding: br, compress, gzip
```

There is another way, you convert the compressed binary to string using the below code, which will be accepted by the client which accepts JSON.

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zip = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(zip, list);
            }
            var byteArray = stream.ToArray();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte item in byteArray)
            {
                sb.Append((char)item);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```